# Retrieve and access value from Tizen's scope outside synchronously

Tags: javascript, tizen, tizen-web-app

May be I am not asking it in right way. I am kind of new on Tizen.
Here is my code set for tizen.

```
respons =   tizen.filesystem.resolve("documents", function(dir) 
                {
                  file = dir.resolve("myfile.txt");
                  if(file.isFile){                  //if file is present then fetch the information.
                    var res_one = file.openStream("r", 
                            function(fs) { 
                               var  my_json = JSON.parse(fs.read(file.fileSize)); 
                               fs.close();
                               res_two = my_json.json_value;
                               return res_two;
                             },
                            function(e) {
                            console.log("Error " + e.message);
                            return null;//if there is any error then return null
                            }, "UTF-8");
                     return res_one;
                  }
                  else{
                  return null; //if file is not present then return null
                  }
        });
```

Basically I have a file present on my display(Installed Tizen OS) that contains a json:
 json_value: "My Information"

I am trying to fetch the information to use that in my javascript code. I am able to fetch that information(Checked using console.log). But it is not being returned in res_one or in response.

In short form I want to access that json outside  tizen.filesystem.resolve( ...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you stored that json file in your filesystem... then how can you want to access it  outside tizen.filesystem.resolve?

Comment: Thanks for reply, It's the requirement buddy. I need to use the stored values in my functionality in java script.

Comment: What does this give ?
 var  my_json = JSON.parse(fs.read(file.fileSize));

Answer (score 1):

I have done it. Basically this is asynchronous behaviour of javascript so I have done it using call back.

```
function to_fetch_the_value_and_chain_process(passed_function){
    tizen.filesystem.resolve("documents", function(dir){
                      file = dir.resolve("myfile.txt");
                      if(file.isFile){      //if file is present then fetch the information.
                        var res_one = file.openStream("r", 
                                function(fs) { 
                                   var  my_json = JSON.parse(fs.read(file.fileSize)); 
                                   fs.close();
                                   res_two = my_json.json_value;
                                   passed_function(res_two);
                                 },
                                function(e) {
                                console.log("Error " + e.message);
                                passed_function(null);;//if there is any error then return null
                                }, "UTF-8");
                         return res_one;
                      }
                      else{
                         passed_function(null); //if file is not present then return null
                      }
    });
}

funtion passed_function(retrieve_res_two){
    alert(retrieve_res_two );
    //use retrieve_res_two and chain the next code here.....
}

to_fetch_the_value_and_chain_process(passed_function);
```

Comment: Is there any way to do it without moving callbacks? I would rather handle the issue by async/await methodology.